# Como acceder a las propiedades de una clase hija desde la instancia de la clase padre

Tags: c#, herencia

Suponiendo que tengo las siguientes clases

```
class Vehiculo 
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}

class Auto : Vehiculo
{
    public string CantidadRuedas { get; set; }
}
```

y lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente

```
Vehiculo vehiculo = new Auto();
// Como acceder a las propiedades de auto?
// al intentar hacer lo siguiente intellisense me dice que vehiculo no tiene tal propiedad
Console.log(vehiculo.CantidadRuedas);
// al intentar usar un cast me sigue sin reconocer la propiedad
Console.log((Auto)vehiculo.CantidadRuedas);
```

La pregunta es: ¿como accedo a las propiedades del elemento hijo en ese caso?

Comment: No estas accediendo en esta línea `Console.log(vehiculo.CantidadRuedas)`? Qué es lo que deseas hacer?

Comment: Hola, estaria entendiendo por los conceptos de herencia que no puedes acceder a los atributos de un hijo desde un padre, ya que esos atributos no los trae el padre pero si los hijos ?

Comment: Todo depende como esten declarados.. si son publicos si. Tal vez deberias decirnos que conceptos tenes y donde los leiste, porque parecen confusos

Comment: voy a cambiar un poco la pregunta a ver si me hago entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que encerar la operacion de casteo dentro entre parentesis para que te retorne la instancias que deseas:

```
Console.Log(((Auto)vehiculo).CantidadRuedas);
```

O tambien puedes utilizar el operador [`as`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) que convierte la referencia al tipo deseado, pero igual tendrás que encerrar la operación dentro de paréntesis para poder obtener acceder la instancia:

```
 Console.Log( (vehiculo as Auto).CantidadRuedas );
```

Comment: estoy obligado a hacer un casteo a otra variable? no puedo hacerlo con la misma variable?

Comment: @LPZadkiel listo, dale una mirada.

Comment: Creo que no entiende el concepto de porque tiene que hacer eso. Seria mejor explicar eso.

Comment: pues yo si entiendo el concepto de eso, de hecho hago lo mismo en typescript para casteos no se como no se me ocurrió acá. Gracias estimado

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres acceder a las propiedades del auto deberias hacerlo de esta forma

```
Auto vehiculo = new Auto();
Console.log(vehiculo.CantidadRuedas);
```

Para que lo que quieres hacer funcione correctamente, deberias saber que el que tiene 'cantidadRuedas' es el hijo, no el padre.
Por lo tanto debes crear una variable del tipo 'Auto'

Pero si lo que quieres es castearlo, como muestras en la pregunta, la solucion es la siguiente

```
Console.log(((Auto)vehiculo).CantidadRuedas);
```

Lo que tienes que castear es la variable, no el valor devuelto

Comment: es necesario usar la clase hijo ? y si quisiera crear varias clases de tipo vehiculo como auto, avion, barco, etc. pero crear una sola variable en un inicio y en base a condiciones crearla como cierto tipo de hijo

Comment: Para llegar a la propiedad que necesitas si es necesario, repito que la propiedad que buscas esta en el hijo y no en el padre por lo tanto deberas castearla necesariamente, y por lo que entiendo de tu respuesta, podras crear una unicamente variable de tipo vehiculo e asignarle cualquier hijo, pero verifica que al castearlo sea correcta la instancia por que si no dara error, podes verificar eso con 'if (vehiculo is Auto)' o 'if (vehiculo.GetType() == typeof(Auto))'

Comment: si entendía el hecho de castearlo pero no se me ocurrió el encapsular el casteo, como lo hacía yo seguía usando la variable original pero encapsulando el casteo entre paréntesis se casteaba como correspondía, gracias por la ayuda!